# CannotPullContainerError on AWS ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

[image: Edit container Image]

I can't quite grok the image `[registry-url]/[namespace]/[image]:[tag]` URL for a [Docker Hub image of mine](https://hub.docker.com/r/hendry/count/) for AWS ECS.

With the Docker client it's just `docker run -it hendry/count`.

So what would Docker Hub's URL for the image?

Answer (score 9):

The registry url is … blank. *Just the same* as the docker command line, if you give ECS an image with no repository url:

```
eventstore/eventstore
```

it will pull it from dockerhub.

(This surprised me too. I spend half an hour searching the interwebs for a url for dockerhub before trying this).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the wrong place. Go to the [repositories view](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=ap-southeast-1#/repositories). From there, it should be very clear what the URL for your image is.

Comment: Don't see any Image URLs or UI for for repositories ... http://s.natalian.org/2016-07-12/1468296944_2558x1404.png

Comment: It doesn't look like you've created any repositories.

Comment: I want to use the public Docker hub one... looking at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_Console_Repositories.html this service is not available in Singapore. :/